# How to change the cell color of a jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker and I need to be able to change the background color for the selected cell date. I'm trying with something like:

```
    $("#fecha").datepicker({ 
          onSelect: function(value, date) { 
             alert(date.css());
          } 
    });
```

hoping that the date parameter refers to the selected cell, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestion?

//Edit:
The solution should let me have different cells with different colors set dynamically, this is why I'm trying with onSelect instead of changing the CSS directly.

The purpose is to have a calendar with events established by the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If a given answer works please mark it as the "answer" to help everyone else. This saves dup questions being asked.

Comment: I know, but I expressed myself badly so I edited the question and I'm waiting for answers before marking the correct one. Thanks for the answer anyway! :D

Comment: Sadly i don't think that is possible. You have access to the onSelect callback, however the contents of the DatePicker get redrawn also and i don't know if this can be stopped. But the the new answer i have given WOULD work if you can stop the date picker getting redrawn.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the best way (assuming i have understood you correctly) is to simply override the css.
In your site stylesheet or html head section you just need to override the following css selector

```css
.ui-datepicker-current-day .ui-state-active { background: #000000; }
```

**EDIT**

With your edit in mind, the following should work (assuming you can get the datepicker to stop refreshing)

```
onSelect: function(value, date) {
    date.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a')
        .css('background-color', '#000000');
}
```

Comment: But if I do it overriding the css it wouldn't allow me to have multiple cells with different colors, right?

Comment: Marked your answer as the correct because it's the best approximation, anyway I didn't get the thing to stop refreshing so I decided to write my own event calendar. Thanks for the interest and the help!!

Comment: No worries, you could always have a look at the very robust datePicker made by Kelvin Luck though - http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/

Comment: this worked: http://jsfiddle.net/abhMH/2/ as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690626/jquery-datepicker-remove-ui-state-highlight-class-onselect-event#12690674

Answer (score 1):

change in your css the class `.ui-datepicker-current-day`

Comment: with the way the css is jQuery css structured, this would be overridden as the above only equals 10 in terms of css cascade-order value. The css requires a value of 20 or more (two classes) to override the jQuery ui css default.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i need to remove active class, so:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      inst.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').removeClass('ui-state-active');
    }, 50);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker by default follows your theme.  But you can override anything.

`ui-state-active` is the style of the date you select.
`ui-state-highlight` is the style it uses to identify the current date.

So do something like this:

```
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-state-active {color: #FFFFCC;}

#ui-datepicker-div .ui-state-highlight {color: #DCDCDC;}
```

You can rather add this css to the page or adjust the theme itself.