# JQuery DatePicker remove today-class

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want the today-cell in JQuery DatePicker to have the same look/behaviour as all other selectable days. I suppose it somthing like removing the class td.ui-datepicker-today. Any suggestions?

Comment: ... or just remove any `.ui-datepicker-today` selector from the CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you.

[How to change the cell color of a jquery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906266/how-to-change-the-cell-color-of-a-jquery-datepicker)

Comment: Thanks. I added the css which solved my problem.
.ui-datepicker-today .ui-state-default{ .. myvalues..}
.ui-datepicker-today .ui-state-active{ .. myvalues..}
.ui-datepicker-today .ui-state-hover{ .. myvalues..}

Comment: Jquery's css has important all over the place so this doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would leave the class as it is, but change the css, so it is the same css as the rest.

The other scenarios are: you change the plugin, but that would be bad, because if a newer version comes out, you'll have to change it again.

OR, you CAN unset the class. But then you would first let the plugin set it, and then you unset it, which is pretty dirty

You can easilly extend the existing css with some new css, so whenever and whatever changes in the future (your mind or the plugin :) ) it will be easy to controll.

Answer (score 0):

you need to over load the class **.ui-state-default ui-state-highlight** in your style sheet 
with the style inside the class **.ui-state-default**