# jquery datepicker remove .ui-state-highlight class onSelect event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am developing the web application, in this application i used the jquery datepicker plugin. I am using the datepicker as inline datepicker. when i select a date, i am trying to remove a css class `ui-state-highlight`, but not reflected in datepicker.

```
    $("#start_date").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: greySelectedDateRange, 
    maxDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        console.log(dateText);
        var toDaysDate = getCurrrentDate('mdy'); //function returning current date
        console.log(toDaysDate);
        //When the selected date is equal to current date 
        if (dateText == toDaysDate) {
            $(this).find('a.ui-state-active')
                   .removeClass('ui-state-highlight')
                   .find('.ui-datepicker-today a')); 
             //$(this).datepicker("refresh");
            //console.log($(this));
        }
    }
});
```

When i see the console `console.log($(this));`, it has been removed, but when i inspect, the css class( `ui-state-highlight` ) is still there, please suggest me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's what you were trying to do, I would change the question to "Remove highlight of today's date (ie "ui-state-highlight" class) in jquery date picker".  I searched for a *long* time to find this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
inst.dpDiv.removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

`inst.dpDiv` is the datepicker div that is generated.

http://jsfiddle.net/abhMH/2/

Comment: hi Johan, Have checked with this code, still it is the same, the change is not reflected, also tried inst.dpDiv.removeClass('ui-state-highlight'); with $(this).datepicker("refresh");, no change yet.
Please left me know, if you have any other solution

Comment: @user665864 An ugly solution would be to wrap your code in a `setTimeout` function. If you run your changes after the html has been generated by the script you should be fine.

Comment: hi Johan, i tried with all the other options left, and at lost used your solution of using setTimeout, it worked finally, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The method suggested by @Johan and @Stano works - but as soon as you change months and then back to the current month, the highlight on today returns. This slight modification fixes this:

```
$(function() {
   $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({    
     beforeShow: function(input, inst) {clearToday(inst)},
     onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {clearToday(inst)}
   });

   function clearToday(inst) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            inst.dpDiv.find('a.ui-state-highlight').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
        }, 10);
}
```

I found I had to reduce the timeout to 10, otherwise the day highlight flickered on briefly and was visible.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if they are adding the CSS class after the onSelect is fired.

One thing you could do is examine the properties that are set for `ui-state-highlight`, and then elsewhere in your code override them:

```
.ui-state-highlight {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```