# jQuery DatePicker background color for cells where event exists (on load)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I want to change the background-color for cells where events exist.

In this case for this day: 2016-04-07

I hope someone can help me, I don't find a solution here in SO.
Thank you

JS code:

```
// I WANT TO CHANGE BACKGROUND-COLOR FOR THIS DAY
var events = {"2016-04-07":[{"title":"Friday!!!!","description":"Weekend is starting!!!"}]};

// Setup our datepicker
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
   dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
   onSelect: findEvents
   });

// Provide a function to find and display events
  function findEvents (date) {  
// Start by emptying our data container
  $("#dateevents").empty();
 // Potential date object
   var dateObj = events[date];
 // If no events exist for the selected date
 if (!dateObj) {
  return $("#dateevents").html( "<h2>" + date + ": No Events</h2>" );  
  }
  // If we've made it this far, we have events!
 $("#dateevents").html( "<h2>" + date + ": " + dateObj.length + " Events Planned</h2>" );
 // Cycle over every event for this date
 $.each(dateObj, function (index, event) {
// Build a list for each event
var $list = $("<ul>");
// Add all event details to list
$.each(event, function (name, desc) {
  $("<li>").html(name + ": " + desc).appendTo($list);
});
// Place list in container
$list.appendTo("#dateevents");
 });
 }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qSCek/6/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the cell color of a jquery datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906266/how-to-change-the-cell-color-of-a-jquery-datepicker)

Comment: @TyrantsBeard not onSelect but when datepicker is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, looping over the html you might want to put it in a function and call it on month change etc.

```
// Provide some event data in JSON format
var events = {"2016-04-07":[{"title":"Friday!!!!","description":"Weekend is starting!!!"}]};

// Setup our datepicker
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  onSelect: findEvents,
});


$("td[data-handler='selectDay']").each(function(index,value){
    var month = $(value).attr("data-month");
    var year = $(value).attr("data-year");
    var day = $(value).next().text();

    var date = year+"-"+(parseInt(month) + 1)+"-"+day


  $.each(events, function(i, v) {
     var parts = i.split("-")
     parts[1] = parts[1].replace("0","")
     parts[2] = parts[2].replace("0","")
     var i = parts[0]+"-"+parts[1]+"-"+parts[2]
     if (i == date) {
        console.log("hit")
         console.log(date)
         $(value).next().css("background","red")
     }
  });
})
// Provide a function to find and display events
function findEvents (date) {  
  // Start by emptying our data container
  $("#dateevents").empty();
  // Potential date object
  var dateObj = events[date];
  // If no events exist for the selected date
  if (!dateObj) {
    return $("#dateevents").html( "<h2>" + date + ": No Events</h2>" );  
  }    
  // If we've made it this far, we have events!
  $("#dateevents").html( "<h2>" + date + ": " + dateObj.length + " Events Planned</h2>" );
  // Cycle over every event for this date
  $.each(dateObj, function (index, event) {
    // Build a list for each event
    var $list = $("<ul>");
    // Add all event details to list
    $.each(event, function (name, desc) {
      $("<li>").html(name + ": " + desc).appendTo($list);
    });
    // Place list in container
    $list.appendTo("#dateevents");
  });
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qSCek/7/

Comment: It would be perfect if it maintained the css after clicking on the day. However thank you very much!!!

Comment: the problem is when you change the month, the css is not remain on the item. I tried the `onChangeMonthYear` option on the datepicker and it doesn't work either

Comment: @Lulylulu yes! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I accomplished to do. The problem I think is that the `onChangeMonthYear` callback is called before the view is rendered. So I put a timeout to solve the problem.

```
// Setup our datepicker
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  onSelect: findEvents,
  onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month) {
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 1, year, month)
  }    
});

var d = new Date();
changeBackground(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1);

function changeBackground(year, month) {
  for (var date in events) {
    var d = new Date(date);
    // if same day and year
    if (d.getFullYear() === year && d.getMonth() + 1 === month) {
      var day = d.getDate();
      // retrieve all elements containing day
      var elements = $('a:contains(' + day + ')');
      elements.each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).text() == day) {
          $(this).css("background", "red");
        }
      });
    };
  }
}
```

And [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/n0bvre3w/)

Comment: If I click on a different day the background goes away, Can you help me? try in your Fiddle please

Comment: You can add a call to `changeBackground` in the `onSelect` callback function `findEvents`. I updated the fiddle with the example.